# Laravel: Show message(alert) on all open tabs, if session variable changed

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, session-variables

Laravel Version: 5.2.45

PHP Version: ^5.4

I have a session variable named `f_year`. It stores the financial year in the session. This can be changed by the user. On changing the `f_year`, the session is reset and page is reloaded.

The problem is that, user changes the `f_year` in one tab and without refreshing the other tab, saves the data. And the year is mismatched.

**Is it possible to show an alert on other open tabs**: *Your Financial Year has changed. Please reload the page to continue.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the other day I ran into a similar issue. What I did was I first set the cookie and a session variable (using PHP). Then I used the JQuery to get the cookie value. The JQuery cookie method, fetches the current cookie set(irrespective of the browser tab).

Then I compared these two values and alerted the user about the mismatched settings.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

An other solution :
It is to associate a session with the selected year (saved on the server DB and added to each page). As the user change the year, the session associated is deleted (the id of the user session changed). 
As the user will try to save data with the deleted session you can respond to the user "The year has changed, the page has been reloaded).

As I speak about session, it could be any information in the $_SESSION[]. So you have to double check Year in server to be the same as year in each of the user request.

Answer (score 0):

@user9141607, you can upgrade Laravel to 5.3 and use [Laravel Broadcasting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/broadcasting) for live-updating information on page without refresh.

Comment: Could you please elaborate